# jQuery Function - return a value with two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, attr

I want to carry a value inside a JavaScript function but use jQuery to detect the click or hover state.

```
function foo(bar){
 var choc=bar;
}
```

When I click `foo()` I want it detect the first click and the second so I can do an image swap.

Example:

```
function foo(bar) {
    var choc=id;    
    $(id).click(function () {
        alert('first click');
    }, function () {
        alert('second click');
    }); 
}
```

I can only return first click. This is what I am trying to do:

An example which will not work

```
<a href="javascript:open(5);" class="open">open <img id="5" class="swap5" src="down.png" /></a> 
<div id="box5">press the up button to close me</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".open").click(function(event){
              var id = event.target.id;
              $('#box' + id).slideToggle();
              $(".swap"+id).attr("src", "up.png");
        }, function () {
                var id = event.target.id;
                $('#box' + id).slideToggle();
                $(".swap"+id).attr("src", "down.png");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.toggle` instead of `.click`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".open").toggle(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          var id = event.target.id;
          $('#box' + id).slideToggle();
          $(".swap"+id).attr("src", "up.png");
    }, function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var id = event.target.id;
          $('#box' + id).slideToggle();
          $(".swap"+id).attr("src", "down.png");
    });
});
```

Also lose the `href="javascript:open(5);"` in the `<a>` tag.  Use `href="#"` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty hacky solution, but here is my take at it.
Declare a counter variable that is initialized at 0.
On click increment it and do a check to see if it is 2 to perform your action.

```
var counter = 0;

function foo(bar) {
  var choc=id;    
  $(id).click(function () {
    if(counter == 2) {
     //Perform action
     counter = 0; //reset counter
    } else {
      counter++;  //Increment counter
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The counter else would keep increasing though.. bizar bonkers solution. Repped anyway due to newb and sheer amusement! Appreciate it though!

Comment: Instead of `counter == 2` you should do `counter %2 === 0`.

Comment: counter would start at 0, then it would first check to see if it is 2, if not it will go into the else where it gets incremented by 1. And it will keep doing this till it hits 2 at which point it gets reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the double click event handler? Check out a description by going to: http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/
It's pretty well documented so you should find it straight forward to implement